# What will be the http status code for data save failed

Tags: rest, http, http-status-code-404

Sent 3 data with post request. For some reason it couldn't be saved on database table. Such as, foreign key constraint failed.
then what will be the http status code?

Comment: Is the client that made the request responsible for the constraint violation? I this case a `409 Conflict` or the generic `400 Bad Request` could be used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What HTTP status code should I return for POST when no resource is created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55685576/what-http-status-code-should-i-return-for-post-when-no-resource-is-created)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`500-599` is reserved for server errors in HTTP response status codes.

`500` specifically is for **Internal Server Error**, which you could throw in the event that a validation error occured.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#server_error_responses